# capify-ec2 cap deploy:migrate db no servers matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I'm unable to perform a `cap deploy:migrate`. And the error message is:

```
2014-10-14 10:01:15 executing `deploy:migrate'
executing "ls -x /home/pj-production/projectname/releases"
`deploy:migrate' is only run for servers matching {:roles=>:db, :only=>{:primary=>true}}, but no servers matched
```

Setup:

rails (3.2.13)

capistrano (2.14.2)

capify-ec2 (1.1.6)

`cap ec2:status`

```
Project: PROJECTNAME.
Num Name     ID   Type     DNS                                    Zone       Roles
00: worker01 i-1 t1.micro  ec2-x1.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com eu-west-1b worker
01: db01     i-d m1.medium ec2-x2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com eu-west-1b
02: web01    i-f m1.medium ec2-x3.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com eu-west-1b web,app,db
```

in deploy.rb:

```
ec2_roles name: :web, options: { default: true }
ec2_roles name: :app, options: { default: true }
ec2_roles name: :db, options: { default: true }
ec2_roles name: :worker, options: { default: true }
```

There are parts in deploy.rb with

```
task :start, roles: :app do
  run "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn/production.conf.rb -E production -D"
end
```

works, for example when i perform a: `cap deploy`, it runs and finishes.

What could be the problem?
I searched with Google and other questions in stack. but couldnt get it to run.
I'm not using multistage btw and a gist file of the deploy.rb: https://gist.github.com/ADogan/2121d312c5938746acd6

Answer (score 1):

For the ec2 instance with the roles: 'web,app,db' you need to add an 'Options' tag in AWS with a single value, 'primary'.  This is equivalent to having a config/deploy/env.rb with the line:

```
role :db, "10.1.2.3", :primary => true
```

Deploy works because it will skip db:migrate if there are no boxes that match the role 'db' where primary is true.  You're specifically asking it to db:migrate, which will fail if there are no boxes to run it on.